# How to create invoices from an external module in odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12, odoo-13

I created a custom module and in that module, the user should be able to create invoices from sales generated in the module.

The function I am using seems to work fine and I can even get the id of the created invoice, but the invoice does not show in the Accounting module of Odoo13.

This is the code am using to create the invoice with:

```
invoice_vals = {
        'partner_id': 1,
        'state': 'draft',
        'invoice_date': self.date,
        'invoice_payment_term_id': 1,
        'invoice_line_ids': [0, 0, {
            'name': 'name',
            'account_id': 2,
            'analytic_account_id': 1,
            'quanitity': 100,
            'price_unit': 100,
        }]
    }
    invoice = self.env['account.move'].sudo().create(invoice_vals)
```

I have hard coded the values for now just to test that it should work.

Comment: You probably missed `invoice_type` and maybe some other fields.

Comment: Little hint: search for something like `prepare_invoice` in the Odoo code. There are already some methods creating dictionaries for invoices like in app `sale`.

Comment: Adding the invoice_type and the other fields helped. Thank you, I can now create an invoice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will create a draft journal entry visible under `Invoicing/Accounting/Miscellaneous/Journal Entries`.

Customer and vendor bills are filtered using `type` field, `out_invoice` for Customer invoice, and `in_invoice` for vendor bill.

Fix `quanitity` field name, it should be `quantity`.

Comment: Yes, without the 'type': out_invoice, entry it creates a journal, but it works fine now.